# Signed requests to AWS API Gateway

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have a Next.js server running within AWS. From this server (not the client), I want to send requests to an [API Gateway](https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) I have configured that authorises requests via [IAM Authorization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-access-control-iam.html).

If I send a request, I get a 403 as expected because there's no signature. I should just be able to use [signed requests](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/create-signed-request.html) to resolve this but the algorithm is fairly complex with plenty of scope for errors so I don't want to have to implement it from scratch.

I've tried using various libraries for this but they seem fairly old or incredibly complicated.

All I want to do is to implement a function like this:

```
export async function sendSignedRequest(request: Request): Promise<Response> {
  // sign request and await response
}
```

Is there a simple, modern way to implement this?

Comment: Did you try the provided example https://github.com/aws-samples/sigv4a-signing-examples/tree/main/node-js. A call with default values seems pretty straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for an API Gateway "Generated SDK":

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html

This allows you to construct a client that will automatically handle request signing, in such a way as:

```
var apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
  accessKey: 'ACCESS_KEY',
  secretKey: 'SECRET_KEY',
});
```